# How to add create the multiple Scanner based on the scanner

Tags: java

I'm a newbie and I want to input by using a scanner.
if I have an integer a, followed by a lines of input (1 <= N <= 100).
eg input:

```
2
a
b
```

Comment: Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ? Also read up about scanner documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Hi @YHStan,
how to show the first row, the user enters the number 2 and then the user can enter 2 rows below..

Comment: let me get this straight, you want the user to input a number, and based on this number you want to get that number amount of inputs again?

Comment: yes, if the user enter 2 and then they can enter 2 row below

Comment: Are you familiar with **loops** (`for`, `while`, `do-while`)?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, what you should do is:
1a) use Scanner's nextInt() method to get the int x followed by nextLine() to clear the \n

or

1b) use Scanner's nextLine() and Integer.parseInt() to get the int x

2. use a for loop to iterate over x ie
   for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {//your code and logics here}

and I cannot stress this enough. Read the documentation.